# Xamarin android release with multiple c++ abis in one package?

Tags: android, c++, xamarin

I have spent some time learning Xamarin and so far I am finding it a great tool. Now that I have finally got to the point of releasing my software I have hit a problem. Only a single version of my C++ dll is included in the android package (Arm64).

I am working with Visual Studio 2017. I added the C++ code as a 'C++ Shared Library (Android, IOS)' so that it compiles as part of my solution. I then add the reference to my xamarin android project to the android C++ project. 
This compiles the dll and works well during development but when I come to release it with the 'Archive' option all I get is the one dll for the currently active ABI.

I thought this would simply be solved by doing a batch build of all ABIs but sadly that hasn't worked. 
I have all the ABI options ticked in the android projects advanced options and I have not ticked the 'create separate packages for each ABI' option so I expect to see a .so file in each of the architecture folders of the APK.

Has anyone else experienced this issue before? I am at a loss as to what I need to do after going through all the Xamarin documentation and searching online. I don't really want to go down the route of adding the .so files directly as content to the project as I am still actively developing and having the dependency link between the two projects seems like the right way to do it. Perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: APK could only target a single ABI. For multiple ABI, you need to create multiple APKs. You could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/abi-specific-apks) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits?authuser=2#configure-abi-split) for more information.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue ? I'm facing the same problem. From what I have read it is possible for apk to target multiple ABI